# What does it mean by "take someone's cut" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "If only the bank would take joy as collateral."
>
> "They may not... but I will. I own 10% of the show. Knowing who I was working for, I had the good sense to **take my cut weekly**."
>
> "Phillip, I can't let you gamble it on me."
>
> *The Greatest Showman*

I guess in this context this sentence means he saved his money for the future, but I'm not sure if I'm right cause I couldn't find any expression like this in the dictionary.

Is it an idiomatic expression?

Or does "take" here mean "save" as a verb, and "cut"="money"?

Comment: Yes, "cut" here means "my share of the profit". Like when you prepare to eat a pie in a company: each one gets his cut (slice) of the pie. Here the person gets his "cut of the money earned by the show" each week.

Comment: See [*cut*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cut): "18. *singular noun* Someone's cut of the profits or winnings from something, especially ones that have been obtained dishonestly, is their share."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He was a 10% owner of the show and was taking 10% of the profits. Because he couldn't trust his partner, he insisted on receiving profits every week, fearing to wait longer in case the money ran out.